# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

How to address the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'`? Its failing in `self.home.get_you_button().click()`. It’s working fine when I am not creating Page Object Class...it clicks on the You button without any error but by using POM it’s failing. The url is https://huew.co/

Code trials:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

class HomePage():

    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def wait_for_home_page_to_load(self):
        wait =WebDriverWait(self.driver,30)
        wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')))

    def get_you_button(self):

        try:
            element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='desktop-public-header']/a[@ng-controller='UserNavigationInteractionCtrl'][6]")

        except:
            return None
```

Comment: So what's the `Exception` you are catching?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: Your `get_you_button()` function explicitly returns `None` in the case of **any** `Exception`. Is it catching one? If so, which one? This should really be included in the question.

Comment: @FynnBecker if element not found it will return None the except block is handling this but here the problem is with Click

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when that function returns `None` and you attempt to call `.click()` on `None`? That would indeed raise the `AttributeError` you are encountering. Did you debug your code to ensure that this is not what's happening? Again, all this information should be included in the question.

Comment: @AvinavDas Even if no exception was raised, your `get_you_button` method doesn't return anything explicitly, which means it will still return `None`.

Comment: Add the relevant code... you keep referring to a click but there is no click in the code you posted. Get rid of the `try-except` and `return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(...)` and you'll find your error.

Comment: https://huew.co/

I want to perform click on 'You' button for the above website. Which locator should I use, I tried with driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='desktop-public-header']/a[@ng-controller='UserNavigationInteractionCtrl'][6]")
 but its throwing error- Nonetype Object has no attribute, means its not identifying the element. This xpath is working if I am not calling this method from Page Object Class (where I stored my web elements)

Comment: Also tried with 
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//div[@class='desktop-menu-icon-text']")[4])
still click operation is not performed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't understand what this AttributeError means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/dont-understand-what-this-attributeerror-means)

Answer (score 5):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

...implies that no *element* was returned by *WebDriverWait* so **None** was returned from the `except` block which have no attribute as 'click'.

As your *usecase* is to click on the element with text as **You** a couple of facts:

- You don't need to wait for *home page to load* with *WebDriverWait* seperately. So you can remove the method `wait_for_home_page_to_load(self)`.
- Instead induce once you invoke `get()` for the url `https://huew.co/` induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired element i.e. element with text as **You** to be *clickable*.
- It will be better to catch the actual exception **TimeoutException**
- Not sure about your *usecase* but there is no point returning **None** rather print the relevant text and `break`.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  self.driver = driver
  try:
      return (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class= 'desktop-menu-container ng-scope' and @href='/profile/']"))))
      print("YOU link found and returned")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("YOU link not found ... breaking out")
      break
  ```
- You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
  ```